# How can I update my Q-table in Python?

Tags: q-learning

I want to implement this function on a voice searching application:

$$
Q(S, A) \leftarrow Q(S, A)+\alpha\left(R+\gamma Q\left(S^{\prime}, A^{\prime}\right)-Q(S, A)\right)
$$

And also restricted to use epsilon-greedy policy based on a given Q-function and epsilon. I simply need a $\epsilon$-greedy policy for updating my q-table.

Comment: At-least show what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try returning a function that takes the state as an input and returns the probabilities for each action in the form of a numpy array of length of the action space (set of possible actions). Here, is one attempt:

```
def EpsilonGreedyPolicy(Q, epsilon, no_of_actions):

    def policy(state): 
        probabilities = np.ones(no_of_actions, dtype = float) * 
                    epsilon / num_actions 
        best_action = np.argmax(Q[state]) 
        probabilities[best_action] += (1.0 - epsilon) 
        return probabilities 
   
    return policy
```